# Advanced search Query "or" not working

Tags: magento-1.7, database, query

I created a file "/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Advanced.php" and copied the core file over I'm trying to modify getProductCollection() to get only products with a certain attribute set to 'yes' in the admin.

Here is my code:

```
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('mc_pin_system_avail')
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addStoreFilter();
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system','eq'=> 1),
                    array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system_avail','eq'=> 1)
                ));
```

It only returns the values with mc_pin_system_avail set to yes. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Did you want `mc_pin_system AND mc_pin_system_avail` as the result or `mc_pin_system OR mc_pin_system_avail`? Currently, the `addAttributeToFilter` is an `OR` statement.

Comment: Yes mc_pin_system OR mc_pin_system_avail because items with mc_pin_system will likely have mc_pin_system_avail set to 'no' in the admin area.

Comment: interestingly enough if I change my code to `this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
     array(
      array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system','eq'=> 'something'),
      array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system_avail','eq'=> 'something')
     ));` I still get the mc_pin_system_avail results. Since these attributes are boolean values do they need to be handled differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue with my results were do to the fact mc_pin_system_avail was added after all products were created in the system. So to return the correct results I needed to edit every product and just save it to provide a default value for mc_pin_system_avail. Also I needed to add 'left' to make sure the values were left joined instead of inner joined.

```
array( array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system_avail','eq'=> 1), array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system','eq'=> 1) ),'left');
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to have a little clarification on the selection you're expecting to occur.
Are you expecting to have only items with `mc_pin_system` attribute and then only items that have `mc_pin_system_avail` set to True?

Setting it out visually in a truth table can help clarify what results you're expecting:

```
mps  mpsa
0    1
1    1

mps  mpsa
1    1
```

Similar situation in unrelated code I was working on yesterday to create separate related product types. The logic for handling selection of attributes ( `addAttributeToFilter()` ) from working code works as follows:

**AND logic:**

```
    /* Add filter to remove Spares and Options, from Related product display */
    $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute'=>'is_option', 'null' => 'true'),
                array('attribute'=>'is_option', 'eq' => '0')
            ), '', 'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute'=>'is_spare', 'null' => 'true'),
                array('attribute'=>'is_spare', 'eq' => '0')
            ), '', 'left'
        )
        ->addStoreFilter()
    ;
    /* End added filter */
```

**OR Logic:**

```
    /* Add filter to remove Spares and Options, from Related product display */
    $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute'=>'is_option', 'null' => 'true'),
                array('attribute'=>'is_option', 'eq' => '0'),
                array('attribute'=>'is_spare', 'null' => 'true'),
                array('attribute'=>'is_spare', 'eq' => '0')
            ), '', 'left'
        )
        ->addStoreFilter()
    ;
    /* End added filter */
```

Currently, your selection is using **OR** logic which will select `mc_pin_system` which can contain items having `mc_pin_system_avail == 0` **OR** `mc_pin_system_avail` which can contain items having `mc_pin_system == 0`

```
$this->_productCollection
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system','eq'=> 1),
            array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system_avail','eq'=> 1)
        )
    );
```

To convert it to **AND** logic so only items with both `mc_pin_system attributes` set to `1` are selected

```
$this->_productCollection
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system','eq'=> 1)
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system_avail','eq'=> 1)
    );
```

Comment: Yes I need the or logic so mc_pin_system_avail=1 mc_pin_system=0 or mc_pin_system=1 mc_pin_system_avail=0. `array(
       array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system_avail','eq'=> 1),
       array('attribute' => 'mc_pin_system','eq'=> 1)
     ),'left');` seems to have done the trick maybe because mc_pin_system_avail was added to the attribute sets later by the clients so there is a null value beacuse it has no default?

Comment: Ok, yes, you have to include null results in your selection for attributes added after the fact. Adding the attribute doesn't add it to its parent item till the next save if a default was set. You'll notice I test for null on the attributes in my top samples, specifically because of this, for attributes that have **No** as their default value, but that haven't been updated since the attribute was created. And `left` is for `left outer join` for SQL SELECT

Comment: `left outer join` sb `left join`

Comment: ok it seems saving them is the only option the client actually edited the ones I thought I was getting by editing my query. I out put the query and it looks like this part is what's messing it up. The inner joins should be left joins.

Comment: INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_mc_pin_system_avail_default` ON (`at_mc_pin_system_avail_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_mc_pin_system_avail_default`.`attribute_id` = '196') AND `at_mc_pin_system_avail_default`.`store_id` = 0 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_mc_pin_system_avail` ON (`at_mc_pin_system_avail`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_mc_pin_system_avail`.`attribute_id` = '196') AND (`at_mc_pin_system_avail`.`store_id` = 1)

Comment: INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_mc_pin_system_default` ON (`at_mc_pin_system_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_mc_pin_system_default`.`attribute_id` = '141') AND `at_mc_pin_system_default`.`store_id` = 0 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_mc_pin_system` ON (`at_mc_pin_system`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_mc_pin_system`.`attribute_id` = '141') AND (`at_mc_pin_system`.`store_id` = 1)